# How to fix PdfArray cannot be cast to PRStream

Tags: java, itext

To read a pdf file, I have used below code segment working with the iText library. However, for some pdf documents, it throws an exception which is shown at below of the code. I donot understand why this exception is sent for some document but for some other it is not thrown. Moreover, how can I solve this problem?

NOTE: Below code is for extracting text from pdf, i.e. pd fto txt converter

```
private ArrayList<byte[]> contentOfPdf() {
    PdfReader reader = null;

    PdfDictionary dictionary = null;
    PRIndirectReference reference = null;

    PRStream contentStream = null;
    ArrayList<byte []> byteStream = new ArrayList<byte []>();

    try{
        reader = new PdfReader(this.filename);

        for(int currentPage = 0 ; currentPage <= this.totalPageNumber ; currentPage ++ ) {

            dictionary = reader.getPageN(currentPage);
            reference = (PRIndirectReference) dictionary.get(PdfName.CONTENTS);
/*line 166*/ contentStream = (PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reference);

            byteStream.add( PdfReader.getStreamBytes(contentStream) );
        }
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        reader.close();
    }

    return byteStream;
}
```

**Exception :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfArray cannot be cast to com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PRStream
at pdfCrawler.retrieveContentOfPdf(CrawlerTask.java:166)
at pdfCrawler.call(CrawlerTask.java:55)
at pdfCrawler..call(CrawlerTask.java:1)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: actually, you don't "fix that". somewhere you are making a logical error of the type to use two unrelated types, or types that are related by a has-a relationship, in an is-a relationship.

you can't cast the one into the other, since there is no is-a relationship. it's like saying that your foot is a shoe, rather than saying you wear a shoe on your foot.

check what the right elements are and use those instead.

Comment: @Stultuske But, it is work for some document, and I get the result. On the other hand, for some document, it throws this exception. These two documents is form of PDF. I wonder why it is throwing exception for some case, and for some other not.

Comment: This question is a duplicate of http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66433 On this other forum, Zmavus says **I just tried to extract the text from pdf.** This is **in total contradiction with the code presented in this question!** Text extraction is done with the `com.itextpdf.pdf.parser` classes, **NOT** by extracting the content stream without taking into account XObjects, fonts and other resources!

Comment: @BrunoLowagie why do I take account into XObjects? Why do I take "fonts" information?

Comment: You say you want to know what text is in a page stream. By ignoring XObjects, you may ignore large pieces of text. By ignoring fonts, your text may seem gibberish (until you know more about the encoding). That's why.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie do you have a tutorial or piece of example which tells how to use xObject. I have read but donot understand how to use

Comment: I could, but that wouldn't be wise because (1) you still would have the problem of interpreting the PDF syntax and converting characters based on encoding. Moreover (2) you are the type of developer that doesn't read answers. If you did, you'd know what to do: http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.java.lib.itext.general/66441

Comment: @BrunoLowagie I have read all the answers and my program is running fine. I have fixed the code and put some recursion into it. Actually, after getting answer, I have took the specification document and tutorial on the one website, and then study on. But, really, I dont get how to use xObject; however, as your last answer,    I think my assumption is wrong which is iText automatically get the Pdf syntax and parse it to the byte stream.

Comment: Your program is running fine, but: (1) do you always get the content in the right order? (2) do you get all the content? Try your code with this PDF: http://examples.itextpdf.com/results/part4/chapter15/hello_reverse.pdf What do you get?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie my aim is to extract words in the document, just words. But, I will test the code with your document to check whether it gets the all content. Thanks

Comment: In that case, you're doing it wrong. You should use the example mentioned on the mailing-list: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=278

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you manually walk a PDF I'd strongly recommend that you have a copy of the PDF spec nearby and look up each and every key. In your case, if you look up the `CONTENTS` key you'll see that it says:

> The value shall be either a single stream or an array of streams.

I'm not a Java guy but the below C# code should be easily converted to Java and should do what you're looking for:

```cs
//Will hold an array of references
PdfArray refs = null;

//If we have an array, use it directly
if (dictionary.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS).IsArray()) {
    refs = dictionary.GetAsArray(PdfName.CONTENTS);
//If we have just a reference, wrap it in a single item array for convenience
} else if (dictionary.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS).IsIndirect()) {
    refs = new PdfArray(dictionary.Get(PdfName.CONTENTS));
//Sanity check, should never happen for conforming PDFs
} else {
    throw new ApplicationException("Unknown CONTENTS types");
}

//Loop through each reference
foreach (var r in refs) {
    //Same code here
    reference = (PRIndirectReference)r;
    contentStream = (PRStream)PdfReader.GetPdfObject(reference);
    byteStream.Add(PdfReader.GetStreamBytes(contentStream));
}
```

Comment: the problem is actually resulting from `PdfReader.getStreamBytes(contentStream)`. It returns PdfArray, i.e. the problem still exists.

Comment: @Zmavus *the problem is actually resulting from* - No, it results from you casting `(PRIndirectReference) dictionary.get(PdfName.CONTENTS)` and `(PRStream) PdfReader.getPdfObject(reference)`. As has been explained both here and on the iText mailing list, the contents can either be a stream or an array of streams. Thus, when you get **Contents**, you may get a reference to a stream, a reference to an array, or immediately an array. Fix your code accordingly.